# How to generate an address size fault on ARMv8 32 bits?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, virtual-memory, armv8

I am new in ARM and I am trying to understand the theory behind address translation in order to generate an address size fault at different levels. I know that during the process from virtual address to physical address translation the Long-descriptor translation table format descriptors are involved. Observing the formats "Block" and "Table" for level 1 and 2 and the format "Page" for level 3, if bits `[47:40]` are not zero then a translation that uses the descriptor will generate an Address size fault.

What I don't understand is why the bits [47:40] will not be zero, that is, if I am working in C and a page of RAM need to be allocated, what possible reason would cause those bits to be set to a non-zero value?

Comment: How does this have anything to do with C?  Did you actually get such a fault in a C program?  Under what OS?  It sounds like you're talking about page-table management details that depend on the OS, not the C program making memory allocations.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry for that. To be honest, I am not an expert in operating systems, the general idea I have is that when a program needs a page of RAM, the operating system is responsible for making that happen, however, I do not know the details of that process. Looking at the ARMv8 reference manual it seems to me that the bits [47:40] are not set by the operating system or software, so I do not understand how the address size fault can occur, can this fault only be generated by the hardware?

Comment: Bits `[47:40]` of what?  The virtual address?  Didn't your title say you're in 32-bit mode where registers / addressing-modes are 32-bit?  (Sorry, I only know HW page-table details for x86; for ARM mostly just user-space / compiler-target kind of things.)

Comment: Im working with 32bit, but ARMv8 use Long-descriptor translation table format. These are 64bit registers. According with the reference manual [39:30]bits specify the output addres, and [51:40] are SBZ (Should-be-Zero). Reference manual says: if [47:40]bits of the descriptor are not zero then a translation that uses the descriptor will generate an Address size fault. In addition: An Address size fault is generated if the translation table entries or the TTBR for the stage of translation have nonzero address bits above the most significant bit of the maximum output address size.

Comment: It seems to me that something should be wrong in the process of translating from VA to PA that causes those bits to be set at a non-zero value, what I am trying to determine is what are the possible causes.

Comment: And you're writing your own custom kernel that manages the page tables?  Or are you getting this error while using some existing mainstream OS?  Please [edit] details into your question.

Comment: Or if you're just wondering how it *could* happen, obviously in a correctly-designed system it wouldn't.  Do 64-bit processes use the same descriptor format?  If so, then they presumably have a purpose for 64-bit processes but must be zero for 32-bit processes.  (That's just my guess based on what you describe, I haven't checked ARM manuals.)